# Как включить верхнюю строку с кнопками?

Tags: android, android-studio

Установил на мак андроид студию и не знаю как активировать верхнюю строку в которой file,  edit,  view,  navigate,  code и т.д.

Вот как нужно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так это сейчас у меня

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Правка**

Вот она))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эта панель в самом-самом верху экрана. Кнопки на ней заменяются на кнопки текущего окна в фокусе

Comment: *тут шутка про фото экрана*

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Добавил фотки в вопрос так как думаю что не совсем ясно преподнес вопрос

Comment: @post_zeew  почему вам так показалось?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Что мне показалось?

Comment: @post_zeew Вы написали, что там шутка. Что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, может у вас какой-то fullScreen режим включён? Попробуйте его отключить.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Не обращайте внимание, это была шутка.

Comment: @post_zeew ))))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  ааа))нашел, я новичок в пользовании мак  и вся проблема в том, что эта строчка заползает вверх и чтоб ее увидеть нужно ткнуть экран сверху)) Но и то она выглядит как системная строчка поэтому я не обратил внимания, но если прочить то видно что это то что нужно))

Comment: @post_zeew нашел))